# Object is nil although it was set in init

Tags: swift

I have an object called navigator, which I set within init. I break on it to make sure it is set. However when an IBAction func, linkButtonClicked, get's called and try's to use navigator I get a nil exception. Why?

```
class HomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let appDelegate:AppDelegate!
    let navigator: Navigator!
    @IBOutlet weak var linkButton: UIButton!
    var destinationView:String?
    var parentViewController:UIViewController?

    @IBAction func linkButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try self.navigator.navigate(to: self.destinationView!, from: parentViewController!)
        } catch {

        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        self.navigator = self.appDelegate.navigator

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        // do resetting here if needed, like empty out data
        linkButton.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Those first two properties should not be IUOs, and if they weren't, the compiler would have helped you solve this by poin]ting out that they weren't initialized properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init?(coder: NSCoder)` initializer gets used when you are retrieving the object from some kind of encoded store such as Core Data. This initializer is required by the `NSCoding` protocol and is used *only* for deserializing the object. Therefore, it *does not* get called at object creation. It only gets called if you serialize the object using `NSCoding` and later deserialize it.

The function you want to override in order to ensure some value will be set in your view is *not* its `init` (and if you really want to use its `init`, the method to overload is `init(frame:)`). Instead, you should set any variables you want to be available in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Much appreciated! One more question. As I said when this controller loads the required init is called, although I'm not using any kind of store or explicit serialization. Where is this coming from and why cant my code make use of it?

Comment: I'm actually not sure on why it is getting called. I suspect this might have to do with how Swift handles object initialization internally, but I really don't know the exact reason.

Comment: `init(coder:)` is the initializer that's used when an object is created from a nib.

Comment: Ok so it must be that it's due to fact that its part of my storyboard, but still why cant I use it?